# Set up Font Awesome 5 Pro with Angular without npm

Tags: angular, sass, font-awesome-5, scss-mixins

So I am trying to use Angular 8 with my Font Awesome 5 Pro fonts, but I dont want to use the npm, is there a way to link the actual css files or the scss files inside it, I have tried a lot of ways but I seem to be missing something out here, if you have any methods or any advice I would be grateful.

Answer (score 0):

Whilst I would recommend using `npm` you should be able to import the Font Awesome CDN URL into your Angular web app by adding something like this into `app.component.ts`

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  styleUrls: 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.9.0/css/all.css'
})
```

As long as you have the site listed in your whitelist it should work with Font Awesome Pro.

I am not sure how this works with their new web kits though.